# can link between my android studio codes and app tools?

Tags: android

I have made an android app , but I didnt like the design that much so I want to ask if there is a way to link between my codes and any other app tools and platefrom that can be published after ?
Thank you so much

Comment: What do you mean by app tools?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I mean I want to work on the graphic design of the app

Comment: I suggest you learn about Material Design.